# smbus not found - Visual studio and ironpython

Tags: c#, python

I am getting a run time error associated with ironpython embedded in a visual studio c# project.

```
        statements.AppendLine(@"import smbus");
        statements.AppendLine(@"import time");
```

When executed I get the error "no module named smsbus"

I am using the iron python to access a raspberry pi GPIO.